# Possible to Automate backup of linksys router?

Tags: wireless-router, forms

My employer would like me to automate the backup and restoration of Linksys WiFi devices on home networks. To do this manually requires logging in, navigating and then downloading or uploading a binary file and the clicking of submit buttons. My application is written in Java.

I looked into it a little and I am wondering if it is a 'difficult' problem. Firstly, as an example, my particular Linksys model router, WRT54G2, needs to be logged into from a welcome page... but to  make a long story short, the html form does not seem to be easily accessible (see appendix A). Once logged in, the script would need to navigate and then push a submit button to download the .bin file.

So I am basically looking for any suggestions or hints related to the following three questions:

1. Does Linksys offer a method for software vendors to access and automate the backup and restore functions?
2. If not, how could I login programatically to Linksys routers?
3. Are there popular scripts that can work with a Java program to navigate HTML pages?

**Appendix A:**
When I go to login to the Linksys router (192.168.1.1) while navigating from an unrelated page (e.g. google.com), I remain on the Google page, but am presented with a popup window for the Linksys credentials (un and pw). When I look at the source code, I don't see any text that relates to the Linksys popup, it just looks like the source code from the previous webpage (e.g., google.com).

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/) should probably allow you to automate the whole process, specifically [selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). Its not java however, and is standalone